# A cell with Data Validation (Drop Down) has a value `undefined`. Why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Spreadsheets with Google Apps Script and I want to get the value of the edited cell which has a drop down list. I debugged using `onEdit(e)` and message box and `e.range.value`.

```
Browser.msgBox(`new value：${e.range.value},old value： ${e.range.old}`);
```

The result is

```
new value：undefined,old value： undefined
```

The value of the drop down cell was `undefined` even if the content is selected. Does that mean a cell with drop down list has no value even if the value can be seen in the formula box?
Maybe it is the specification of `Data Validation` or `Criteria` but I couldn't understand [the reference of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation). Is it possible to let the drop down list cell have the value which is written in the formula box?

Below is the full code of `onEdit` function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
      Browser.msgBox("おんえでぃっとだ");
      const sheet =  e.source.getActiveSheet();
      const row = e.range.getRow();//数字
      const column = e.range.getColumn();//アルファベット
      Browser.msgBox(`行列は取得した:(${row},${column})`);
      
      const rule = e.range.getDataValidation();
      const criteria = (rule == null) ? null:rule.getCriteriaType();
      Browser.msgBox(`るーるとくらいてりあもいけた。るーる：${rule}くらいていりあ： ${criteria}`);
      Browser.msgBox(`new value：${e.range.value},old value： ${e.range.old}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) of the properties of the event object:

- To get the new value: `e.range.getValue()` or `e.value`
- To get the old value: `e.oldValue`

**Solution:**

```
Browser.msgBox(`new value：${e.value},old value： ${e.oldValue}`);
```

---

You can also print the parameters of the event object yourself:

```
Browser.msgBox(JSON.stringify(e));
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I should have searched myself further in the official document.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the old value and current value of an edited cell on an `onEdit(e)` trigger using `e.oldValue` and `e.value` respectively:

Sample Sheet:

[image]

Sample Code, using a dropdown box:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  console.log(e.oldValue);
  console.log(e.value);
}
```

Sample Output:

[image]

### Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events